# How to check tinyint column value in mysql table is true or false using linux bash scripting?

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, shell, unix

I have mysql database table that have the following structure

```
+------+-------------+----+----+--------+----------------+
| Field| Type        |Null|Key | Default|Extra           |
+------+-------------+----+----+--------+----------------+
|id    |int(11)      |NO  |PRI | NULL   | auto_increment |
|c_date|date         |NO  |    | NULL   |                |
|c_time|time         |NO  |    | NULL   |                |
|number|varchar(11)  |NO  |    | NULL   |                |
|data  |varchar(150) |NO  |    | NULL   |                |
|isSent|tinyint(1)   |NO  |    | NULL   |                |
+------+-------------+----+----+--------+----------------+
```

What I want is to check whether isSent field's value is true or false or ,0 or 1 using a linux bash script.

Comment: You have the query result stored already? file? variable?

Comment: @Inian No I want to check and set the flag true or false according to isSent boolean field

Comment: I meant if you have the above table stored in a file. If that is the case, please use my answer below

Comment: @Inian Thank you sir. The above table not stored in a file .

Comment: How to you intend to parse the output from?

Comment: Here I have used this table to copy specific records to sms gateway queue   table (kannel  sqlbox) if isSent=0.

Comment: Ouput the query (`select .. > file`) and run the awk command on that file

Comment: Thanks again. I'll try that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using below query you can get the result into variable

```
count=$(echo "SELECT isSent FROM TABLE WHERE ...." | mysql <DB> -u -p -h localhost)

echo $count
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply sir. I'll check your solution.

Comment: Yes , it works . I've used it as 'count=$(echo "SELECT isSent FROM send_sms_scheduler " | mysql sms -u root -p -h localhost)' and returns the result as **isSent 0 0 0 0 0**.

Comment: @kaviranga : then please mark this answer as accepted answer else it will show as unanswered question